# Doctrine ODM(mongo) - upsert embeded document if not exist

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

A mongo document exists which links Users and Cars.  It contains the following fields:

- User.userId
- User.cars[]
- User.updated
- User.created

User.cars is an array of embedded documents.  A query needs to be written to only insert a Car to this field if it does not already contain a Car with id $carId

The following query will create a new record each time for $userId and $carId.  What it should do is either not insert a new record or update the value for driven.

```
    $qb
        ->findAndUpdate()
        ->upsert(true)
        ->field('userId')->equals($userId)
        ->field('cars.id')->notEqual($carId)
        ->field('cars')->addToSet([
                'id' => $carId,
                'driven' => new \DateTime(),
        ])
        ->field('updated')->set(new \DateTime())
        ->field('created')->setOnInsert(new \DateTime())
        ->limit(1)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Removing notEqual($carId) from the query will always insert the record into User.cars, which is also not desired.

The end result should be that User.cars only contains one record for each carId.

Comment: Do you also want to update `"driven"` within the array if then element was matched? It is kind of redundant to use `$addToSet` if in fact you have one part "unique" ( the "id" ) and the other part variable ( the "driven" value ) since any variation in the "driven" value means a new entry. It also should be apparent that the `$ne` check in the array cannot be used at the same time as an "upsert", since any missing element results in a new "document" rather than a new array element. There are existing answers to this process. Have you looked for them?

Comment: Yes most answers suggest doing it as two queries. The first does an update to `driven` where `userId` and `cars.id` match. If no update happens perform a second query which is the above query without `notEqual($carId)`, however I want to modify the query to prevent the possibility of the second query running twice and inserting the car twice into the set.  If the query can be made to fail if `$carId` already exists in the set that would be acceptable.

Comment: It's not really as case of "suggest", but rather that it is just plainly not possible to do otherwise. I ask because your `$ne` check suggests you have seen something to at least realize the intent. And in fact when mixing with a "document upsert" it's **three** updates. There is no way around it. What you have read is what you have to do.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321684/1283381 has ` $ne : MERCHANTID ` which is being use to avoid concurrent issues.  It is this that I am trying to replicate in my query with `notEqual($carId)` - from what you are saying this is not possible?  Sorry I am not following what you mean by it's three updates - are you saying that mongo runs three updates for my query?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to search the array of `cars` later you could store it as an object instead and use `$carId` as key:

```
$qb
    ->findAndUpdate()
    ->upsert(true)
    ->field('userId')->equals($userId)
    ->field("cars.$carId")->set([
            'id' => $carId,
            'driven' => new \DateTime(),
    ])
    ->field('updated')->set(new \DateTime())
    ->field('created')->setOnInsert(new \DateTime())
    ->limit(1)
;
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

If `cars` are mapped in the document as `EmbedMany` you may need to change your [collection's strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/storage-strategies.html) to either `set` or `atomicSet` (I'd suggest the latter) as otherwise ODM will reindex your array each time it's saved.

Once again, this solution has its downsides which can be considered serious depending on how you want to use your data but it solves the problem in question.

Offhand, `->limit(1)` is superfluous as `->findAndUpdate()` is making a query run [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) command which by its nature operates on single document.